# Angular 7.3.9 ERROR ts(37,44): error TS1109: Expression expected

Tags: angular, angular-material, typescript-typings

I'm using Angular 7.3.9  and my code is as follows;

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; 
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { ICAREServices, IMASTServices } from 'src/app/services'; 
 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mast-service',
  templateUrl: './app-mast-service.component.html',   
  styleUrls: ['./app-mast-service.component.scss']
})
export class AppMastServiceComponent implements OnInit {
  billItemTypeIds : number[] =[-5,-6,-8];
  billItemTypeId : number;
  billItemTypeMast : any;
  billItemMast : any;
  billItemMastByType : any;
  searchColsForm : FormGroup; 
  
  constructor(private icareservices: ICAREServices,private formBuilder : FormBuilder,private toastr: ToastrService,private imastservices: IMASTServices ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.icareservices.listBillItemTypeMastByIds(this.billItemTypeIds).subscribe(response =>{
      this.billItemTypeMast =response;
    })

    this.icareservices.listBillableItems().subscribe(response =>{
      this.billItemMast =response;
    })    
    
    this.searchColsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      serviceType : new FormControl(),
      serviceId : new FormControl()     
    });                
    
    this.searchColsForm.get('serviceType')?.valueChanges.subscribe(
      data=>{
        this.billItemMastByType = this.billItemMast.filter(item => item.allergyTypeCode === data);
      }
    )
   
  }

}
```

I am getting the following error

> ERROR in src/app/hims/app-mast-service/app-mast-service.component.ts(37,44): error TS1109: Expression expected.
> src/app/hims/app-mast-service/app-mast-service.component.ts(43,3): error TS1005: ':' expected.

I have tried to run it without following part

```
 this.billItemMastByType = this.billItemMast.filter(item =\> item.allergyTypeCode === data);
```

But still showing same error!

Comment: Line 43 looks ok to me, however this import `from 'src/app/services'` doesn't seem correct (this would mean an npm package named `src`). Try some form of relative path starting with a dot or two, eg. `from './src/app/services'` - sometimes these seemingly unrelated things turn out to matter. If this doesn't help your idea is very good: try bisecting the code.

Comment: Which lines are Line 37 & 43?

Comment: I believe it's complaining because of the null chaining operator, it thinks it's a ternary, that's why it expects the `:`. You should double check what exactly is `this.searchColsForm.get('serviceType')` returning (whether it's nullable or not), what version of TS you are using, and if you have spaces around that question mark, remove them.

Comment: Yes. It works now.   null chaining operator was the issue. Thanks Octavian.

Answer (score 0):

Optional chaining is supported since TS 3.8. The first angular version to support TS 3.8 is v9.

This means you can't use optionnal chaining in your v7 app.